# Битрикс: не отображать определенное свойство в детальном просмотре новости

Tags: веб-программирование, битрикс

Для `div`'a галереи в детальном просмотре новости нужно устанавливать значение аттрибута `data-count` из свойства "Сколько фото ставить в ряд?" (`MORE_PHOTO_COUNT`).

В параметрах компонента в Настройках детального просмотра в поле "Свойства" выбрал это свойство, но мне не нужно, чтобы оно отображалось на странице детального просмотра новости.

```
"DETAIL_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
    0 => "ASSIGNMENT",
    1 => "SOLUTION",
    2 => "SERVICES",
    3 => "MORE_PHOTO_COUNT",
    4 => "",
),
```

Код вывода свойств такой:

```
<?foreach($arResult["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"] as $pid=>$arProperty):?>

    <b><?=$arProperty["NAME"]?></b>:&nbsp;
        <?if(is_array($arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"])):?>
            <?=implode("&nbsp;/&nbsp;", $arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"]);?>
        <?else:?>
            <?=$arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"];?>
        <?endif?>
        <br />
    <?endforeach?>
```

Помимо этого свойства есть 3 других, и они должны отображаться. [См.скриншот](http://prntscr.com/a3xnx2).

Как это сделать правильно?

В файле `template.php` код подстановки значения для аттрибута `data-count` такой

```
<div class="gallery" data-count="<?echo $arResult['DISPLAY_PROPERTIES']['MORE_PHOTO_COUNT']['DISPLAY_VALUE'];?>">
<?
        if(count($arResult["MORE_PHOTO"])>0):?>
        <?foreach($arResult["MORE_PHOTO"] as $PHOTO):?>
<a class="fancybox" data-rel="group" href="<?=$PHOTO["SRC"]?>"  title="<?=$arResult["NAME"]?>"><img alt="<?=$arResult["NAME"]?>" src="<?=$PHOTO["SRC"]?>" title="<?=$arResult["NAME"]?>"></a>
        <?endforeach?>
    <?endif?>

</div>
```

Также добавил файл result_modifier.php, в нем такой код:

```
<?
$APPLICATION->SetTitle("");
?><?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();

$arResult["MORE_PHOTO"] = array();   
   if(isset($arResult["PROPERTIES"]["MORE_PHOTO"]["VALUE"]) && is_array($arResult["PROPERTIES"]["MORE_PHOTO"]["VALUE"]))   
   {   
      foreach($arResult["PROPERTIES"]["MORE_PHOTO"]["VALUE"] as $FILE)   
      {   
         $FILE = CFile::GetFileArray($FILE);   
         if(is_array($FILE))   
            $arResult["MORE_PHOTO"][]=$FILE;   
      }   
   }   
?>
```

Comment: кроме массива `DISPLAY_PROPERTIES` есть еще массив `PROPERTIES` используйте его если нужно получить информацию о свойстве, которое не нужно отображать.

Comment: Николай, спасибо, то, что нужно!

Answer (score 1):

если нужно использовать значение\параметр свойства, которое не нужно отображать, то пользуйтесь массивом `PROPERTIES`.